# How to skip initial OnChildAdded event firing in Firebase Database

Tags: java, spring, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

There is a users subtree in my Firebase Database which keeps basic user info and following/followers for that user, this subtree is structured like this:

```
"users": {
  "userId-1": { 
    "userName": "Namey McNameface",

    "following": {
      "followingId-1": true,
      "followingId-2": true,
      .
      .
    },
    "followers": {
      "followerId-1": true,
      "followerId-2": true,
      .
      .
    }
  },
  "userId-2": {},
  "userId-3": {},
  .
  .
}
```

I want to send a notification to user's phone whenever someone starts to following him/her. 
In my own server, I listen to the followers subtree. When a child added, user will see a notification. 
The problem is that, at some point I will need to deploy the next version of my server and when I do that `OnChildAdded` event will fire for all children (followers) and all users will see wrong notifications about their followers starting to follow them.

I can store the sent-notification info in my database to solve this problem, but this will be a time-consuming job for me.

Another way is that I can skip the initial firing of `OnChildAdded` event, if that is possible in Firebase Database.

Thank you in advance.

**Edit:**

I am using Java and Spring for my server.
This is my `FirebaseService`. I am creating a UserListener and starting to listen all users.

```
@Service
public class FirebaseService {
    public FirebaseService() {
        UserListener userListener = new UserListener();
        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(Tag.USERS).addChildEventListener(userListener);
    }
}
```

This is `UserListener`. It creates a `FollowerListener` to listen `followers` subtree for each user.

```
public class UserListener implements ChildEventListener {
    @Override
    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
        String userId = dataSnapshot.getKey();
        FollowerListener followerListener = new FollowerListener(userId);
        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(Tag.USERS).child(userId).child(Tag.FOLLOWERS).addChildEventListener(followerListener);
    }

    @Override
    public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
}
```

This is `FollowerListener`. When a user ID is added to `followers`, FollowerListener sends notification. It basically gets the followed user's FirebaseInstanceId and follower user's screen name. Then sends notification.

```
public class FollowerListener implements ChildEventListener {
    private final String followedUserId;

    public FollowerListener(String followedUserId){
        this.followedUserId = followedUserId;
    }

    @Override
    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
        String followerUserId = dataSnapshot.getKey();
        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(Tag.USERS).child(followedUserId)
                .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        User followedUser = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);

                        if(followedUser != null){
                            FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(Tag.USERS).child(followerUserId)
                                    .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                            User followerUser = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);

                                            if(followerUser != null){

                                                // Send notification to followed user.

                                                NotificationInfo notificationInfo = new NotificationInfo();
                                                notificationInfo.setTitle("test title");
                                                notificationInfo.setText(followerUser.getScreenName() + " seni takip etmeye başladı.");
                                                notificationInfo.setClickAction(Tag.ACTION_GO_TO_PROFILE);

                                                NotificationData data = new NotificationData();
                                                data.setUserId(followerUserId);

                                                NotificationRequestBean bean = new NotificationRequestBean();
                                                bean.setTo(followedUser.getFirebaseInstanceId());
                                                bean.setBody("test body");
                                                bean.setTitle("test title");
                                                bean.setPriority("normal");
                                                bean.setDelayWhileIdle(false);
                                                bean.setNotification(notificationInfo);
                                                bean.setData(data);

                                                AppUtils.sendNotification(bean);
                                            }
                                        }

                                        @Override
                                        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                                        }
                                    });
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
    }

    @Override
    public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
}
```

The problem is whenever I deploy the server, FollowerListener attaches to all users's `followers` subtree. Then OnChildAdded event is firing for each follower initially. It should not send notifications every time I deploy the server.

Thanks.

Comment: Please include the [minimal code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in your question.

Comment: AngularFire2 deals with this issue - using the JS API - by listening to the `child_added` events and the first `value` event. Firebase orders the events so that the `child_added` events that fire for existing data occur before the first `value` event; those that fire afterwards are for newly added data. You should be able to do something similar with the Android API, although the event handling differs significantly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a very simple solution for this problem. I just added a `boolean` field in the `followers` subtree called `processedByServer`. So it became like this:

```
"followers": {
  "followerId-1": {
    "processedByServer": true // already processed.
  },
  "followerId-2": {
    "processedByServer": false // not processed yet, but will be.
  },
  .
  .
}
```

This `processedByServer` is initially `false`, after I made my necessary processing in the server (send notification etc.) I change this value to `true`. The server only needs to process when this field is `false`. So after I redeploy/reboot my server, it won't send wrong notifications anymore.

But there is also downsides of this solution:

1. I added an extra field just for that, but I think it's ok.
2. When the server restarts, it has to check all of the `processedByServer` fields in the `followers` subtree, which may be a time consuming job for the server.